# Replacing List value using dictionary that contains an underscore

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am trying to use a dictionary to replace usernames with their real names.  For example, if the input is "bob2000", the dictionary will replace the list value as "Bob Doe".

However, I am getting an problem with a username with an underscore.  The value does not get changed.

For example,

```
my_dict = {
     'bob2000':'Bob Doe',
     'bob_2001':'Bob Smith'}
```

Returns:

```
my_list = ['Bob Doe', 'bob_2001']
```

The value is simply getting skipped over. My code is shown below.

```
def name_replace(my_list):
    data = [my_dict.get(item,item)  for item in my_list]
return (data)
```

Comment: You code is somewhat pointless. You could clarify what you want, since the intent of your code is unclear.

Comment: You need to return `data` not `my_list`..

Answer (score 2):

From function `name_replace` return `data` not `my_list`

```
my_dict = {
     'bob2000':'Bob Doe',
     'bob_2001':'Bob Smith'}
my_list = ['Bob Doe', 'bob_2001']
def name_replace(my_list):
  data = [my_dict.get(item,item)  for item in my_list]
  return (data)
print(name_replace(my_list))
```

> Output: ['Bob Doe', 'Bob Smith']

Comment: I accidentally had my return as my_list, when my code was returning data.  The problem still persists, only for names with underscores.  Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: give sample input and expected output and what you are getting